# JavaScript scoping, parameter in function same as local variable in function?

Tags: javascript

when I have a function, does the parameter passed in have the same scope to a callback method inside the function?  that is, in the following function are both xx and yy valid?

```
onMyFunction: function(component) {
  var myLocal = 7;
  my.load({
    callbackfunction: function() {
       // can I access both
       var xx = component;
       var yy = myLocal;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes. You could have just tried that ;)

Comment: Felix, I have tried in different forms and have gotten results that confused me.  I'm hoping to hear from experts more than just yes or now, but thinking behind it if there are subtle differences I'm not understanding between passed in parameters and local declared vars.  Wasn't trying to waste your time.

Comment: You could post the results that confuse you, and ask for an explanation, maybe that would help you more? There is not much more to say about this. Parameters are scoped exactly like local variables and for all intents and purposes behave exactly like local variables.

Comment: thanks, that is the answer I was looking for.  As is normal, my confusion is coming from a much larger project which is why I boiled my question down to a very simple example to try and confirm my understanding of what is going on (and not just assume because I concocted one example that worked, my understanding must be correct).

Comment: In fact, when a function is executed, parameters and variables are stored in the same internal "map", so during runtime, it would not even be possible to distinguish between parameters and variables. At least according to the specification: http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are scoped exactly like local variables and for all intents and purposes behave exactly like local variables.

In fact, when a function is executed, parameters and variables are stored in the same internal "map", so during runtime, it would not even be possible to distinguish between parameters and variables. At least [according to the specification](http://es5.github.io/#x10.4.3).

Answer (score 4):

yes they are both valid.. that is what closures are for...

Comment: so basically, the incoming parameter is exactly the same in scoping to a local variable?

Comment: yes.. basically the function 'callbackfunction' that you are declaring is created along with a internal structure that points to those  variables.. so it still has access even when the outer funciton returns and the stack is long gone..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, javascript does scoping mainly by functions so all the references you have available in a function block will also be available to any function or block declared within it.

If you're interested in the subject, i'd recommend
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md
especially the part on Function/Block Scope and also Scope Closures.

:)